# HTML Open Link in New Fixed Size Window

Tags: html, popup

I am trying to add a pop up confirmation window for a contact us form I am making.  I want a new html page to to open up in a new window that has a fixed size and is centered in the users screen.

Ideally I would love to only use HTML/CSS but I don't know if that is even possible. If not I don't mind using Javascript or jquery if it's simpler.

Thank you!

Answer (score 29):

```
<a href="#" onClick="window.open('yourpage.htm','pagename','resizable,height=260,width=370'); return false;">New Page</a><noscript>You need Javascript to use the previous link or use <a href="yourpage.htm" target="_blank">New Page</a></noscript>
```

Comment: I assume this gets eaten by popup blockers more-so than target="_blank".  Of course this actually works to get a real new window (and not a new tab) and allows you to set size.  So like everything, it has pros and cons.  Thanks for answering!

Comment: Can't you do the same with `<a href="yourpage.htm" target="_blank" onClick="window.open('yourpage.htm','pagename','resizable,height=600,width=800'); return false;">New Page</a>` ?

Comment: To add positioning:
[link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Window-Browser/Openanewwindowsettingheightwidthandposition.htm)
[link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a65eba52-db5a-430e-8e19-190199382d46/how-to-set-popup-window-opening-position?forum=asphtmlcssjavascript#:~:text=User1206592506%20posted-,Hi%2C,to%20achieve%20the%20desired%20position.)
Note: This works fine on the 1st monitor, 2nd mon known issue, unresolved in chrome. [link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=137681) [link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1336616)