# Enable resizing of popup window

Tags: html, css, resizable

```html
<table style="margin:5;Width:1000px;Height:150px;">

    <td class="text">
      <br>
        Click on the link to open a chat room. <br>
        Ask your question.<br>
        <br>
        <a href="link" target="_blank"          onClick="window.open('link','pagename','resizable=1,height=700,width=550'); return false;">Chat</a>
        <br>
        <br>
        </td>
    
</table>
```

I want the window to open with height=700,width=550, and let the user have the option to resize the window if needed.

An example is if the user has a high-resolution scale in Windows.

Comment: take a look at this it should do the trick. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444356/html-open-link-in-new-fixed-size-window KR

Comment: Oh, i think if there is a same question exist, you should delete this question to avoid repeat.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML Open Link in New Fixed Size Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444356/html-open-link-in-new-fixed-size-window)

Comment: i have tried 'resizable,height=700,width=550' but its not letting me resize the window. When i open the window and i try to resize it, the window just jumps back to original size

Comment: I've tried your code, and it works for me (I'm using Google Chrome). When browser are you using?

Comment: Google Chrome and Edge Chromium

Answer (score 0):

Found the issu in the popup window i self.

´´´
< META NAME="viewport" CONTENT="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, **user-scalable=no**, minimal-ui"/>
´´´´